# Javascript Date - getDate gives different results in different years

Tags: javascript, date

I have two date strings - same month, day and time, but different year (2017, 1970). When I convert them to Date object and then use `getDate()` function, I get different day.

```
var d1 = '1970-05-11T22:00:00.000Z';
var d2 = '2017-05-11T22:00:00.000Z';
console.log(new Date(d1), new Date(d1).getDate()); // day 11
console.log(new Date(d2), new Date(d2).getDate()); // day 12
```

Why is that so and how can I control this behavior?

Comment: I get 11 for both.  What timezone are you in, and did the rules for Daylight Savings change between 1970 and 2017 where you are?

Comment: can you `console.log(new Date(d1) + '', new Date(d1).getDate());` and `console.log(new Date(d2) + '', new Date(d2).getDate());` - I suspect daylight saving issue too

Comment: Works for me too .. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzF8I.png

Comment: I get 12 for both :p because Australia

Comment: `getDate()` converts to whatever timezone is configured in your browser. You can alternatively use `getUTCDate()` instead

Comment: Oh, I see - it must be daylight savings change in play here. I guess using `getUTCDate()` should fix this

Comment: `1970-05-11T22:00:00.000Z` is `1970-05-11T23:00:00.000 GMT+1:00` (czech standard time) ... `2017-05-11T22:00:00.000Z` is `1970-05-12T00:00:00.000 GMT+2:00` (czech summer time)

Comment: That explains it then - from [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/czech-republic/prague?year=1970): _"Daylight Saving Time (DST) Not Observed in Year 1970 ... Prague observed Central European Time (CET) all year."_

Comment: @JamesThorpe great, please write this as answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your profile indicates that you're in the Czech Republic.  `getDate` returns values for the local time.  In 2017, [according to timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/czech-republic/prague?year=2017), Daylight Savings was observed and was in effect in May.  However, [it also says that](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/czech-republic/prague?year=1970) during 1970:

> Daylight Saving Time (DST) Not Observed in Year 1970
>
> Prague observed Central European Time (CET) all year.
>
> DST was not in use in 1970.

The 22:00 in your UTC times is close enough to midnight for `getDate` to return the next day in your timezone, since it was the 12th local time in 2017, but still the 11th in 1970.

You can fix this by using `getUTCDate` instead, which returns 11 for both:

```js
var d1 = '1970-05-11T22:00:00.000Z';
var d2 = '2017-05-11T22:00:00.000Z';
console.log(new Date(d1), new Date(d1).getUTCDate()); // day 11
console.log(new Date(d2), new Date(d2).getUTCDate()); // day 11
```

Comment: Worth noting that it is only since ECMAScript 2015 (ed 6) that implementations have been expected to make their ["*best effort*"](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-daylight-saving-time-adjustment) to determine historical daylight saving changes.